# Confusion regarding quantum point contact conductance

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, transport-phenomena

In the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_point_contact) Quantum Point Contact (QPC) page the conductance is described as a function if the gate voltage, and has discrete jumps of the size of the conductance quantum $G_0 = 2 e^2/h$. In this [Nature paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12713) there a setup with a quantum point contact but the gate voltage instead controls the transmission $D$ of the quantum point contact, which is a number between $0$ and $1$. The current then is given by $D G_0 V(t)$.

To me there seems to be an apparent contradiction, where in the Nature paper it seems like the conductance is not quantized, varying continuously.

Is the difference that when $D$ is not integer there are reflections? But then why not define the conductance as $D G_0$?